# heroku git:clone doesn't do anything

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Newly installed heroku toolbetl on Windows 7.

Tried cloning an app using:

```
heroku git:clone -a myappname
```

And I get

```
Cloning from app "appname"...
```

And then nothing happens. No empty repository, no nothing.

I tried this with two different apps.

Can you help me find a way to start debugging why is this not working? Thanks

Comment: what version of the Toolbelt are you on? `heroku version` to see. Lastest is 3.7.3. I just tried on Mac OS and it worked as expected.

Comment: I just tried with Windows 7 and Heroku 3.7.3 and had no issue, can you paste the full output?